# react.ga: how to get the data created in the 'set' API

Tags: google-analytics, react-ga

I am trying to integrate Google Analytics into my react app. And currently I'm using the `react-ga` library.

It's a little confusing or unclear to understand the API `set`.

```
ReactGA.set({ userId: 123 })
```

There is not too much explanation about its functionalities. So what's the purpose of this API, and how to get the data set in the API?

Comment: same issue here 6 years later.. (

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This API is used to set the userId in the user explorer tab in your google analytics account. so that you can view the events, page views with respect to that user ID.

This is basically to track the users based on their userID.